# more < operator in subprocess call Python

Tags: python, csv, subprocess, call, cat

I have three csv file: *1.csv*, *2.csv*, *3.csv* like these:

```
➜  ~  cat 1.csv 
1,1,1,1,1,1
➜  ~  cat 2.csv 
2,2,2,2,2,2
➜  ~  cat 3.csv 
3,3,3,3,3,3
```

If I do:

```
➜  ~  cat < 1.csv < 2.csv < 3.csv > 4.csv
```

I obtain:

```
➜  ~  cat 4.csv 
1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3
```

as I want.

Now I want to do this in Python subprocess.call

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.call('cat < 1.csv < 2.csv < 3.csv > 4.csv', shell=True)
```

but the result is:

```
➜  ~  cat 4.csv 
3,3,3,3,3,3
```

In these ways it doesn't create 4.csv file:

```
sp.call(['cat', '<', '1.csv', '<', '2.csv', '<', '3.csv', '>', '4.csv'], stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE
```

Or

```
mylist = ['cat', '<', '1.csv', '<', '2.csv', '<', '3.csv', '>', '4.csv']
sp.call(mylist, stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the shell either...

Comment: Does your cat command really return you this: 
`1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3` ? In bash it returns `3,3,3,3,3,3`. This is the expected behavior unless you buffer the inputs from 1.csv and 2.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these work:

`sp.call('cat 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv > 4.csv', shell=True)`

and

`sp.call('cat < 1.csv > 4.csv', shell=True)
sp.call('cat < 2.csv >> 4.csv', shell=True)
sp.call('cat < 3.csv >> 4.csv', shell=True)`

Not sure what your real objective is. If you just want to concatenate some files then doing it directly in python is the way to go. If you want to chain-append some program outputs then I would do it using the 2nd method (one per line).

Comment: This way with subprocess.call is faster than python way...I have to concatenate csv files with more than 10 millions of lines.

Comment: @maxv15: [you don't need `shell=True` here even if you use `subprocess`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29351066/4279)

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved easily using just python:

```
import fileinput
with open("4.csv", "a") as out:
    for f in fileinput.input(["1.csv","2.csv","3.csv"]):
        out.write(f)
```

Using subprocess you could redirect:

```
from subprocess import check_call
with open("4.csv", "a") as out:
     check_call(["cat", "1.csv", "2.csv", "3.csv"],stdout=out)
```

I would recommend using the first example.

Comment: First example is a good pythonic way...but I have to join big files (csv with more than 10 million of lines) and subprocess.call is faster.

Comment: upvote for the pure Python solution. You could write `check_call(['cat', '1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv'], stdout=out)` instead of the second code example.

Answer (score 1):

If you redirect multiple times, all the redirection are performed, but only the last redirection will take effect (assuming none of the earlier redirection cause error).

```
$ cat < 1.csv < 2.csv < 3.csv > 4.csv
```

The above is equivalent to :

```
$ cat < 3.csv > 4.csv
```

unless either of 1.csv, 2.csv or 3.csv doesn't exists in which case this command will expected to fail.

Try this :

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call('cat  1.csv  2.csv  3.csv > 4.csv', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the [`fileinput` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351066/4279) is too slow, you could try to copy using larger chunks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from shutil import copyfileobj

with open('4.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    for filename in ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            copyfileobj(file, output_file)
```

[`copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) accepts `length` parameter that you could experiment with to find out how it affects the time performance in your case.

If it is not enough, you could try [`os.sendfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sendfile):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

with open('4.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    for filename in ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            while os.sendfile(output_file.fileno(), file.fileno(), None, 1 << 30) != 0:
                pass
```